# Creating a new user in Disco Dingo?

Tags: users

I am planning to create a new user in Disco Dingo,
How do you create a new user in `Disco Dingo`?
                                                                 Any risks involved?
How to delete the account?                                                                                        What are the differences from the admin account-no power on sudo.

Comment: It is where is the button to mark it?

Comment: The button to or link mark it duplicate.